Which edge bar should be used to join Runner carpet on stairs and Wood flooring?
What would be the right spec for an edge bar to use on joining parts for wood flooring and runner stairs. Looked into few of those, including Z Edge bar but none looked right. Can't find a Z Edge with half gripper.
Would the correct bar require pulling the top flight carpet to be pulled a bit as carpet is already installed?


This is largely a matter of design preference. Mine is that metal bars are almost always crutches against higher-quality solutions. In this case I'd have probably run the wood floor out to the nosing to avoid an awkward height difference in the middle of the tread and terminated the runner underneath it.
Since that ship has sailed, I'd probably still treat the wood floor separately with a termination and simply butt the runner into it, possibly rolling it under before tacking it in place. You could also notch a standard edge termination for the runner and set it over the top, resting on the white tread at the ends. Sometimes that results in spongy support, though. Some strategically placed flat-head screws could offer solid support through the runner.

I think what I'd do here is get a couple pieces of white carpet (same thickness as runner) and use a carpet-laminate transition piece across the top.  The carpet pieces would fit to either side of the runner, to basically keep the transition piece consistent all the way across.
